# Component included in a layout has no id in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got some very awkward situation going on. I've created a custom layout component, made up of 5 ImageViews:

select_players_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.lzwierko.SelectPlayerItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/armyImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/army_symbol" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".06" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".40" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:src="@drawable/icon0"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconUser"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".08" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:src="@drawable/icon3" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconProfileAi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_4" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".06" />
    </TableLayout>

</org.lzwierko.SelectPlayerItem>
```

org.lzwierko.SelectPlayerItem class extends FrameLayout:

```
   public class SelectPlayerItem extends FrameLayout {
```

Now I include 4 of this components in my other component:

```
<include
                android:id="@+id/player1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                layout="@layout/select_players_item" />
```

now as you can see I id this include with

```
android:id="@+id/player1"
```

The surprise is that in runtime although I see the components properly on the device, the

```
   findViewById(R.id.player1)
```

returns null. So I've checked with the Hierarchy Viewer and I see that these components have NO_ID in id's, instead of the ones that I've set in xml file.

Can anyone help me with that? I really need to access these components by id.

Comment: ok, I've found the issue, it was in my own code (obviously). I've overridden the setId() method and so the view builder (or whatever it's called) was not setting the original view but some other propery. bugger me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get a reference to the Layout which has the `include` in it, and then using that get the player1 view? Something like:

```
View layout = (View) findViewById(R.id.layout_all);
layout.findViewById(R.id.player1)
```